# Почему не работает td:hover?

Tags: css

Есть цикл foreach и в нем ячейки `<td>` почему не работает стиль

```
td:hover {background-color:#......};
```

Comment: При чем тут php?)))

Comment: При том, что в просто странице html работает

Comment: Проверяйте вывод. Ищите незакрытый тег, стиль с !important, класс с перегружающими стилями. Так же, если у вашей таблицы свой класс и он описан в css после td, может перекрывать. В любом случае косяк в конечном html, а пхп сюда имеет такое же отношение, как процессор сервера.

Comment: Приведите кусок кода, отвечающий за вывод.

Comment: И в каком браузере тестите!

Comment: Не все браузеры поддерживают :hover...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало. Ошибка была в том, что забыл присвоить общий класс к таблице.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть:

1. Файл со стилем может не подключен или не неправильно.
2. Может быть в файле css конфликт с совпадением классов.
3. Кривой браузер(хотя такое элементарное свойство должен поддерживать любой браузер).

Пожалуйста, киньте фрагмент кода, как попросили пользователи выше, а лучше весь файл и мы увидим точную причину.